# PHP Check if it contains anything but alphanumerical, or spaces

Tags: php, string

I have a form that sends a string.  Simple as this:

```
<form action="test2.php" method="POST">
String: <input type="text" name="string" />
<br /><input type="submit" value="Send >" />
</form>
```

Here is test2.php:

```
<?php
$string = $_POST['string'];
preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/", "", $string {
echo "You can't have any symbols in your username.";
} else {
echo "Nice string!";
}
?>
```

It doesn't work. I'm trying to do it so if the string contains anything **BUT** alphanumerical characters or a space, (so any other symbols), it will say you can't have symbols. But if it does only contain alphanumerical, or spaces, it will say Nice String.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I get a fatal error with this.  http://3v4l.org/hDWnf

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is completely invalid. You want something like this:

```
<?php
$string = $_POST['string'];
if ( preg_match("/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/", $string) ) {
    echo "You can't have any symbols in your username.";
} else {
    echo "Nice string!";
}
?>
```

Note that I am using `preg_match` to test whether the regex matches, rather than `preg_replace`, which replaces parts of the string.